# Misunderstanding of a rule about /boot folder (FHS)

Tags: filesystems, boot, fhs

In *Filesystem Hierarchy Standard* [it is said](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s05.html) as to the **/boot** folder that it must contain static files of the boot loader. And there is another rule which states that

> Programs necessary to arrange for the boot loader to be able to boot a
> file must be placed in /sbin.

Can someone explain what this line is about, probably by providing a few examples of programs concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FHS also says "`/boot` stores data that is used before the kernel begins executing user-mode programs".

In case of GNU GRUB, the GRUB modules (`normal.mod` for example) are stored in a sub-directory of `/boot`, specifically at `/boot/grub/<GRUB architecture name>/`.

---

> Programs necessary to arrange for the boot loader to be able to boot a file must be placed in `/sbin`.

In other words, `/sbin` is the place for programs that are not needed at boot time, but are needed to *install* or *(re)configure* a bootloader, like `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig`.

Note that since the release of FHS 3.0 in 2015, several distributions have decided to start the process of merging `/bin`, `/lib` and `/sbin` to `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/sbin` respectively. The expected result is to eventually have `/bin`, `/lib` and `/sbin` as backwards-compatibility symlinks to the corresponding directories under `/usr`, so in modern systems, the bootloader installation/configuration tools may in fact be found in `/usr/sbin` already.